# How capture textbox value on load ? Jquery with knockout

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I need to capture my value of textbox and want to store it in a Hidden field .

On my first load i load value in textbox from database and i need the same value to be placed in some sort of hidden field which makes my work easieer .

**Cshtml :**

```
 <input type="hidden" id="sal3" />

 <input type="text" id="txtSalesPerson1" data-bind="value:$data.SalesPerson1"/>
```

This is how i tried to assign value to hidden field but i done on button click WHICH i dont need in this case .

```
 $('#sal3').val($('#txtSalesPerson1').val());
```

I am looking for this because before user changes textbox value and before he saves value back to database , I need to CAPTURE the value in textbox which is present on my initial load .

Tought of hidden field is best but on fly i have no clue how to approach .

Altough i can get things work but i need to use viewbag etc which is easy but lengthy approach which i am completely against it .

So any toughts are appreciated

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bind your hidden input to an observable like this one:

```
viewmodel.SalesPerson1.InitialValue = ko.observable(null);
viewmodel.SalesPerson1.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    if (viewmodel.SalesPerson1.InitialValue() == null)
        viewmodel.SalesPerson1.InitialValue(newValue);
});

<input type="hidden" id="sal3" 
       data-bind="value: $data.SalesPerson1.InitialValue" />

<input type="text" id="txtSalesPerson1" data-bind="value:$data.SalesPerson1"/>
```

If you need it in several places, you could even write an extender:

```
ko.extenders.initialValue = function (obs, options) {
    obs.InitialValue = ko.observable(null);
    obs.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        if (obs.InitialValue() == null)
            obs.InitialValue(newValue);
    });
}

viewmodel.SalesPerson1.extend({ initialValue: true });
```

Comment: actually i done this in much simpler manner . in my ajax get method i am storing like this which works awesome in my case :  `$('#sal3').val(data.SalesPerson1);` . My html looks like `<input type="hidden" id="sal3" />` .. Cheers

Comment: Possible add the code in your solution as other way . actually your code also works fine but hope someone gets benifit of my way and yours . Thank you so much

Comment: @supercool I prefer to avoid mixing jQuery and knockout when possible. Feel free to add your own answer and accept it if you find it more suitable to your needs :)

Comment: nah you are right . I feel your comments makes sense and will there be any issues if we mix ?

Comment: @supercool why take the risk? :) In this case probably not, but you never know how your code will evolve, maybe there would be in the future

Answer (score 1):

Simply put it in `document.ready` in your view and after page load it will set textbox value in hidden field.

do like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$('#sal3').val($('#txtSalesPerson1').val());

})
```

Comment: If the value is set by knockout, you might read it before it is written

Comment: Ehsan ty for reply but it wont work in my case becoz first document.ready fires asusal later my  knockout viewmodel which holds textbox value fires . so by the above approach  i cant  store a value  in hidden field in advance  into hiddenfield where still textbox dont have actual value  .

Comment: then the way you are binding to textbox bind that to a hidden field as well

Comment: yeah issue solved mate . Ty for helping and your time . binded to hidden filed in my knockout . now works cool